# Shipping Python interpreter with C++ project

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2022, python-install

Problem description:
I have a Visual Studio 2022 C++ project that involves live python script interpretation. Naturally, I need a valid Python installation to do this. However, I intend to ship this as an application, so I'd like to have a localized Python installation, to avoid consumer-side installation, but that doesn't interfere with Windows' Environmental Variables.

What I've done:
I included "Python.h" from my Python installation's "include" folder, I've added its "libs" folder to "Additional Library Directories", I've added "python311.lib" to "Additional Dependencies", and I remembered to copy Python311.dll to my project's Solution Directory.
**Everything is linked properly.**
However, when I run compile and execute my program, I receive a long list of errors, which are as follows:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Coding Projects\MaSGE\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE\\x64\\Release\\MaSGE.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE\\x64\\Release\\MaSGE.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE\\Lib',
    'C:\\Coding Projects\\MaSGE\\DLLs',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000399c (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Of particular interest to me are the first two lines, plus the "PYTHONHOME = (not set)" and "PYTHONPATH = (not set)" on lines 4 and 5 which, to my knowledge, are Environmental Variables.

This brings me to the crux of the problem:
Is there some way in which I can install a portable Python interpreter to a specific folder to circumvent the issue with Environmental Variables?

Comment: This is why installers exist.

Comment: This is not remotely helpful.

Comment: Conversely, you must made someone do a basic google search and read the docs for you. And you didn't (as of my writing) even upvote the answer you chose. If you're not restricted to a single, specific version of python, I'd rather have an installer that installs pre-requisites for me instead of potentially giving me 'n' different instances of the same thing scattered throughout my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed python into your application, you need two things:

### Initialize isolated python

This will not let user's system interfere with your app.

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#init-isolated-conf

### Deploy python stuff with your application

On windows, you need:

1. Python DLL (`python311.dll`).
2. Python standard library.
   Either copy `Lib` folder from python installation, or zip its contents and name it after python dll (e.g. `python311.zip`), or use the same zip from Windows embeddable package)
3. Python modules (`DLLs` directory)

On linux, situation is slightly different:

1. Python shared library (`libpython311.so`)
2. Python standard library (Either copy `lib/python311/` folder from python installation, or zip its contents **except `lib-dynload` folder** and name it `lib/python311.zip`)
3. (If using zipped standard library) Copy `lib-dynload` to `lib/python3.11/lib-dynload`

Of course, you have to replace `311` and `3.11` with your version of python.